# SQL Server: How to convert column into one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have one column with different values depending on result.
I would like to return one row with fix columns.

The column output as follows:

```
Group | Item
--------------
  G1  | 1
  G1  | 2
  G2  | 3
```

I would like to output as:

```
Group | Item1 | Item2 | Item3
-----------------------------
  G1  |   1   |   2   | N/A
  G2  |   3   |  N/A  | N/A
```

Please Help..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: How do the database tables look? (schema)

Comment: Do you have a maximal number of columns?

Comment: Each group can have less or 3 items..

Comment: @ankIT you wrote `G2  | 3` so under item 3 you should have 3. and not as you wrote ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because every group may have three items maximum, I would use [PIVOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
     RowID  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Group]VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,Item   INT NOT NULL
    ,UNIQUE ([Group], Item)
);  
INSERT  @Test   VALUES ('G1', 1);
INSERT  @Test   VALUES ('G1', 2);
INSERT  @Test   VALUES ('G2', 3);

WITH PivotSource
AS
(
    SELECT   t.[Group], t.Item
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.[Group] ORDER BY t.RowID) RowNumber
    FROM    @Test t

)
SELECT   pvt.[Group]
        ,Item1 = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), pvt.[1]) , 'N/A')
        ,Item2 = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), pvt.[2]) , 'N/A')
        ,Item3 = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), pvt.[3]) , 'N/A')
FROM    PivotSource src
PIVOT   ( MAX(src.Item) FOR src.RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3]) ) pvt;
```

Results:

```
Group      Item1       Item2       Item3
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
G1         1           2           N/A
G2         3           N/A         N/A
```

Comment: Hello bogdan.. I thought this will be an easy task but it i not so easy.. Actualy I have one more column, Item_Rate, now my table will have 7 columns, so what I shoud do???

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Now, it will return just two rows. Thanks.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Great solution. I love Both Pivot And CTE.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I think the OP has a mistake : `G2  | 3` that means under item3 - it should have 3 and not like he/you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this will work:

```
SELECT t1.[Group], t1.Item, t2.Item, t3.Item
from tbl t1, tbl t2, tbl t3
where t1.[Group] = t2.[Group] and t1.[Group] = t3.[Group]
    and t1.Item < t2.Item and t2.Item < t3.Item
    and t1.[Group] in (select [Group] from tbl group by [Group] having COUNT(*) = 3)
union
SELECT t1.[Group], t1.Item, t2.Item, NULL
from tbl t1, tbl t2
where t1.[Group] = t2.[Group]
    and t1.Item < t2.Item
    and t1.[Group] in 
    (select [Group] from tbl group by [Group] having COUNT(*) = 2)
union
select tbl.[Group], tbl.Item, NULL, NULL
from tbl
where [Group] in (select [Group] from tbl group by [Group] having COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Comment: You're right. My solution is not very elegant performance-wise (it uses a lot of cartesian products and subqueries).

Answer (score 0):

As you have a fixed number of output columns you can do some tricks with [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [`over (partition by ... order by ...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

```
select child1.[Group], child1.Item as Item1, child2.Item as Item2, child3.Item as Item3 from 
(select [Group], Item from 
    (select  [Group], Item, (ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [group] order by item)) as rownum from GroupTable) as child1_inner
    where child1_inner.rownum = 1) as child1
left outer join 
(select [Group], Item from 
    (select  [Group], Item, (ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [group] order by item)) as rownum from GroupTable) as child2_inner
    where child2_inner.rownum = 2) as child2
on child1.[Group] = child2.[Group]
left outer join 
(select [Group], Item from 
    (select  [Group], Item, (ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [group] order by item)) as rownum from GroupTable) as child3_inner
    where child3_inner.rownum = 3) as child3
on child1.[Group] = child3.[Group]
```

This returns `null` instead of `N/A`, but you can fix that with [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).